# How can I create Cron Expression which works between particular times

Tags: cron

I am working on a Cron Expression for a job that has to run on weekdays every 10 mins from 7.30 am to 8.20 am(inclusive).

The trigger used by me:-
0 30/10 7-9 ? * SUN,MON,TUE,WED,THU *

Issue is it works beyond 8.20 as well? Can we limit it to specific minutes or end time? like 7:30-8:20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things you cannot do in a single expression and you might consider to use two:

```
# Example of job definition:
# .--------------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |       .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |       |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |       |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |       |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |       |  |  |  |
# *       *  *  *  *   command to be executed
# This runs on 7:30, 7:40, 7:50
 30/10    7  *  * 1-5  command
# This runs on 8:00, 8:10, 8:20
 0-20/10  8  *  * 1-5  command
```

Another way you could attempt this is by using a test.

```
# Example of job definition:
# .--------------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |      .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |      |   .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |      |   |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |      |   |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |      |   |  |  |
# *      *   *  *  *   command to be executed
*/10    7,8  *  * 1-5  testcmd && command
```

Where `testcmd` is an executable script that could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
hours=$(date "+%H")
minutes=$(date "+%M")
(( hours == 7 && minutes >= 30)) || (( hours == 8 && minutes <= 20 ))
```

Other examples of this *trick* can be found here:

- [Cron expression to run every N minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176613/cron-expression-to-run-every-n-minutes/)
- [How to schedule a Cron job to run 4th week of the year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48417100/how-to-schedule-a-cron-job-to-run-4th-week-of-the-year/48420387#48420387)
- [how to set cronjob for 2 days?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382634/how-to-set-cronjob-for-2-days/48547339#48547339)